# django OneToOne reverse access

Tags: database, django, one-to-one

I have these simple classes

```
Class A(models.Model):
    ...

Class Meta(models.Model):
    a = models.OnetoOneField(A, primary_key=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=100)
```

but when I do

```
a = A()
meta = Meta()
a.save()
meta.a = a
meta.save()
print a.meta.width
```

i get

```
'A' object has no attribute 'meta'
```

Why is this? Am I using OneToOne wrong? if so how can i get the correct print statement?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use Meta. It is used elsewhere in Django already.

Comment: yes the use of Meta is pretty confusing. you also use Meta.a and a=A() which adds to the confusion

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Define a `related_name` to call the reverse accessor.

```
a = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='foobar')
# ...
a.foobar
```

Comment: You could use a.meta instead of a.foobar in the absence of a related_name. But definitely don't call a model 'Meta'.

Comment: Also useful to mention, if you don't use `related_name`, use model name with all letters in lower case. For example, if you have ExtraModel instead of Meta, you should access it like this: `a.extramodel`.

Comment: ref.: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/